# Problemas al instalar un npm (google sheets). Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Instalé Google spreadsheet para implementar en un proyecto de angular con `npm i google-spreadsheet --save`

Luego creo un service. Declaro una constante con:

```
 const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
```

Ésto me arrojó muchos problemas de dependencias y webpacks, que pude solucionar.
Pero ahora en la consola al cargar la página me aparece esto:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at loadProxy (gaxios.js:52:19)
    at Object.8073 (gaxios.js:61:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.5670 (index.js:16:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.2088 (index.js:10:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.8291 (googleauth.js:19:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.9138 (index.js:17:22)
```

Todos los problemas siempre nacen en la constante que declaré. Pienso que lo estoy haciendo mal, no sé como solucionar algo tan fácil.

Acá está declarada.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const documentID = "...";
//const credenciales = require("../json/credenciales");
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GoogleSheetsService {

  constructor() { 
    
  }
}
```